# Transfer an anaconda environment using an "usb key"

Tags: anaconda

I'm using two windows_x64 PCs with portable instances of anaconda.
One can't reach online repositories. How can I transfer the environment I created on connected PC to the other using my USB key (Sneakernet).

Environment was created using:

```
conda create -n py27 python=2.7 basemap ...
```

Using `conda list --explicit` and some `wget` I managed to get some relevant bz2 files. However what are the next steps ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Solved using :

```
conda create -n py27 afirstpackage.bz2
```

then execute

```
for %i in (*.bz2) do conda install -n py27 %i
```